# how to capture SSH operator output to a variable in airflow using xcoms or any other way

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to xcoms in airflow and unable to get exact information , we have an ssh operator task as below with "echo" command

```
task_id = SSHOperator(
    task_id="task_id",
    ssh_conn_id="CONNECTION_ID",
    command="echo Failed"
)
```

is there any way to capture the above task output to a variable like

```
variablea = "Failed"
```

Any suggestion pls.. I tried xcom push=True but it is displaying blank value..

Comment: Did you pass `do_xcom_push=True`?

Comment: @rdas , yes i have added but unable to capture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While trying to use xcom push it displays something output as "VHJ1ZQo=" or with different characters. Any suggestion pls

SSH operator returns bytes object if pickling is not enabled (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/a8856833e2f6f9eb306e64c96b391e71b2933583/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py#L173-L176)) if `enable_xcom_pickling` is false (which is the [default](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#enable-xcom-pickling)) the return value from the command is being encoded with Base64 and then pushed to Xcom. If you will decode `VHJ1ZQo=` from Base64 you will get `True`.

You need to decode the value you read from Xcom before you use it.
You probably just need to run

```
import base64
....
xcom_pull_value = func_to_get_xcom() # replace how you retrieve the xcom
value = base64.b64decode(xcom_pull_value).decode('utf-8')
print(value)
```

to get the value after decoding from base64.