# Airflow : xcom value from sshoperator not decoding to string

Tags: python, encoding, base64, airflow, decoding

I have an Airflow task, which runs one ksh script in sshoperator and I am sending one value from the script, which I want to use in next task. But as my airflow enable_xcom_pickling is False, I am getting the xcom value in base64 encoded as per the source code in ssh.py.
But When I am trying to decode the value in airflow I am getting some unicode bytes again.

```
base64_message = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='bash_operator_0') }}"
base64_bytes = base64_message.encode('utf-8')
message = base64.decodebytes(base64_bytes)

bash_operator_0 = SSHOperator(
        task_id="bash_operator_0",
        ssh_conn_id=Variable.get('connection_id'),
        command="/path1/path2/path3/testscript.ksh",
        dag=dag)

bash_operator_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_operator_1",
        bash_command="echo " + str(message) + " from bash_operator_1",
        dag=dag)
```

Output i am getting for str(message) is as below

`b'\\xb5\\xab`

xcom value I am getting is as below

`MTAwCg==`

Can anyone please help with the decoding ! Thanks in Advance.

Airflow Version : 2.2.4

Python: 3.6.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH operator returns bytes object if pickling is [not enabled](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/717426ec40bbdd31c564c1d4bdc6ba6e0789d1a2/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py#L174-L176)

Unlike the case of [how to capture SSH operator output to a variable in airflow using xcoms or any other way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73832509/14624409) you can not use Python functions here because they will be evaluated as top level code in `bash_command`. You need to use bash commands:

This will work:

```
xcom_pull_value = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='bash_operator_0') }}"
bash_operator_1 = BashOperator(
    task_id="bash_operator_1",
    bash_command=f"""echo '{xcom_pull_value}' | base64 --decode""",
)
```

Example DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 2, 1)
}

with DAG('xcom', schedule=None, default_args=default_args):
    @task(task_id="bash_operator_0")
    def push():
        return "MTAwCg==" # byte string equal to 100

    xcom_pull_value = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='bash_operator_0') }}"
    bash_operator_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_operator_1",
        bash_command=f"""echo '{xcom_pull_value}' | base64 --decode""",
    )

    push() >> bash_operator_1
```

Render Tab:

[image]

Log Tab:

[image]

Now that this works you can modify the command to anything you like as long as it's valid bash command

Comment: I added above , but DAG parsing failed with error ```bash_command="echo " + base64.b64decode(base64_message).decode('utf-8') + " from bash_operator_1",
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 0: invalid start byte```

Comment: I think the value you have in Xcom is not a valid one? Is the code you posted your real code or are you making adjustments to it? `print(base64.b64decode("MTAwCg==").decode('utf-8'))` will print `100` so please double check

Comment: Below is my actual code, which is failing while parsing the DAG and giving above mentioned error ```base64_message = "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='bash_operator_0') }}" 
bash_operator_1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="bash_operator_1",
        bash_command="echo " + base64.b64decode(base64_message).decode('utf-8') + " from bash_operator_1",
        dag=dag)```

Comment: But If I keep these commands inside a PythonOperator and print the value I am getting 100 which is correct
```def python_func(**kwargs):
        ti = kwargs['ti']
        base64_message = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='bash_operator_0')
        print(base64.b64decode(base64_message).decode().strip())

python_task_1=PythonOperator(
        task_id="python_task_1",
        python_callable=python_func,
        dag=dag)```